# Stopping Go routine from tests

Tags: go

I have a node that I want to spin up until I decide I want to stop it. I currently have a Start method that blocks on the Contexts Done channel, I then have a Stop function that calls the cancel, in my tests my Start seems to hang forever and the Stop is never called. I can't work out why the Done signal isn't being called and stopping my node.

```
var (
    // Ctx is the node's main context.
    Ctx, cancel = context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    // Cancel is a function used to initiate graceful shutdown.
    Cancel = cancel
)

type (
    Node struct {
      database *store.Store
    }
)

// Starts run the Node.
func (n *Node) Start() error {
    var nodeError error

    defer func() {
        err := n.database.Close()
        if err != nil {
            nodeError = err
        }
    }()

    <-Ctx.Done()

    return nodeError
}

// Stop stops the node.
func (n *Node) Stop() {
    Cancel()
}
```

And my test is:

```
func TestNode_Start(t *testing.T) {
    n, _ := node.NewNode("1.0")
    err := n.Start()
    n.Stop()
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code. Let's break it down.

```golang
var (
    // Ctx is the node's main context.
    Ctx, cancel = context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    // Cancel is a function used to initiate graceful shutdown.
    Cancel = cancel
)
```

These should not be package variables. They should be instance variables--that is to say, members or the `Node` struct. By making these package variables, if you have multiple tests that use `Node`, they will all step on each others toes, cause race conditions, and crashes.  So instead, do this:

```golang
type Node struct {
    database *store.Store
    ctx      context.Context
    cancel   context.CancelFunc
}
```

Next, we see that you have a deferred function in your `Start()` method:

```golang
// Starts run the Node.
func (n *Node) Start() error {
    var nodeError error

    defer func() {
        err := n.database.Close()
        if err != nil {
            nodeError = err
        }
    }()
    /* snip */
```

This does not do what you expect. It closes the database connection as soon as `Start()` returns--before anything possibly has a chance to use it.

Instead, you should close the database connection as part of your `Stop()` method:

```golang
// Stop stops the node.
func (n *Node) Stop() error {
    n.cancel()
    return n.database.Close()
}
```

And finally, your `Start()` method blocks, because it waits for the context to cancel, which cannot possibly be canceled until `Stop()` is called, which is only ever called after `Start()` returns:

```golang
func (n *Node) Start() error {
    /* snip */

    <-Ctx.Done()

    return nodeError
}
```

I cannot think of any reason to have `<-Ctx.Done` in `Start()` at all, so I would just remove it.

With all of my suggested changes, you should have something like this:

```golang
type Node struct {
    database *store.Store
    ctx      context.Context
    cancel   context.CancelFunc
}

// Starts run the Node.
func (n *Node) Start() {
    n.ctx, n.cancel = context.WithCancel(context.Background())
}

// Stop stops the node.
func (n *Node) Stop() error {
    n.cancel()
    return n.database.Close()
}
```

Of course, this still leaves open the question of if/where/how `ctx` is used. Since your original code didn't include that, I didn't either.

Comment: My node needs to be running from the Start function and only ever return if Stop is called. So removing the <-Ctx.Done stops it from running until that happens

Comment: Then you must call `Stop` from a separate goroutine.

Comment: In my test should it be as simple as calling `go n.Stop()`

Comment: I've tried calling the Stop in a go routine and it still seems to hang forever @Filmzy

Comment: `go n.Stop()` probably won't work, since the goroutine won't be executed until after `Start()` returns, which in turn never returns until `Stop()` is called. You instead need something like `go n.Start()`.